# Return original exception to the client instead of returning CamelExecutionException Apache Camel

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I have a camel context defined inside an XML based spring context file.
There is one route, which is being invoked by the SOAP(XML) web service client bean. 
While calling the route, it throws some exception and the client receives Camel Exception, instead of the original exception.

> Camel response to the client on exception is shown below

---

```
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-CZC4101XJV-53724-1497351782614-9-2]</faultstring>
  </soap:Fault>
```

> **Expected response** should be the ***original exception message*** on
>   any exception

---

```
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>blah blah blah Number Not valid, I am the original exception</faultstring>
  </soap:Fault>
```

---

> Here is my camel route definition

```
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:remove" />
        <to uri="bean:removeBean?method=validationNubmer" />
        <to uri="bean:removeBean?method=checkBusiness" />
        <to uri="bean:removeBean?method=triggerRemove" />
    </route>
```

> And below the SOAP bean operation which sends an XML request to the
>   route

```
public void removeMe(String id) {
    RemoveRequest request = new RemoveRequest();
    request.setId(id);
    producer.requestBody("direct:remove", request);
}
```

I read the exception clause topic from the Apache Camel documentation, but I couldn't find any information on how to return the original exception to the client, sad!! any help?

> I tried using camel onException but no luck :(

```
    <onException>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="0" />
        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>
        <transform>
            <simple>Error Occurred: ${exception.message}</simple>
        </transform>
    </onException>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on `handleFault` to let exceptions automatic be transformed to SOAP faults. See Camel in Action 2 book, chapter 11, which has a little example: https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter11/errorhandler#1136---handling-faults

Or you need to use `<setFaultBody>` instead of `<transform>` to tell Camel you are setting the message body as a SOAP fault.

Comment: Thanks Claus, I tried both options, one by one and together, but no luck.

Comment: Thanks Claus, Sorry for being late to add my comments because I wanted to test first. I tried both the options, one by one and together, but no luck. The initial project was in blueprint, where I did my test with your suggestions, but the result was same, so I thought, It may be because of blueprint dependencies. Later I migrated the project to spring-boot with Camel, and applied your suggestions, but again no luck. I guess I might be missing something, as I could recall I had used 'handleFalt' on camelContext in past and it had worked. I am using camel 2.19.0.  Any suggestion @Claus